# How to know when to use t-value or z-value?

Tags: statistics, estimation

I'm doing 2 statistics exercises:

The 1st: An electrical firm manufactures light bulbs that have a length of life that is approximately normally distributed with a standard deviation of 40 hours. If a sample of 30
bulbs has an average life of 780 hours, find a 96% confidence interval for the population
mean of all bulbs produced by this firm.

The 2nd: A random sample of 10 chocolate energy bars of a certain brand has, on average, 230
calories per bar, with a standard deviation of 15 calories. Construct a 99% confidence
interval for the true mean calorie content of this brand of energy bar. Assume that the
distribution of the calorie content is approximately normal.

I look at the solution my teacher provided. The 1st one use z-table and the 2nd use t-table. Could anyone tell me how to know (from questions) whether to use z or use t? And please show me the differences between 2 exercises here that make one use  z-value and the other use t-value.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Normally, you use the t-table when the sample size is small ($n<30$) and the population standard deviation $\sigma$ is unknown. Z-scores are based on your knowledge about the population’s standard deviation and mean. T-scores are used when the conversion is made without knowledge of the population standard deviation and mean.
Here is a road map:
[image: ![enter image description here]
In this case, both problems have known population mean and standard deviation. Thus you should only decide based upon whether the sample size is below $30$. 
The 1st problem has $n=30$, so you should use z-table.
The 2nd problem only has $n=10$, so you should use t-table.

[Image Source](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/hypothesis-testing/t-score-vs-z-score) (possibly).

Comment: in the case of the t-score: how can you generate a confidence/probability when you don't know the mean/standard-deviation?

Comment: Why are you required to know the population mean and standard deviation to use the z-score? According to the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) a sample's mean and variance approach that of the population as the sample size grows. Therefore, can't you logically use `z-score` for large values of `n`?

Comment: This is wrong. If the population is normal and you know the population standard deviation you should always use z-score, even if the sample size is less than 30.

Answer (score 1):

In the first problem the *population* standard deviation is known. So one uses the normal distribution.

I would interpret the second problem as saying that $15$ is the *sample* standard deviation. So one uses the $t$-distribution, although for sample sizes say above $50$, the normal distribution, though technically wrong, is probably accurate enough.